# arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF won't work with resolution and world file?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff, advanced-license-level

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
path = "C:\\fakepath\\test.tif"
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, path,   resolution = 820 , world_file = True)
```

The above code produces:

> TypeError: PageLayoutObject: Error in executing ExportToTIFF

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, path,   resolution = 820 )
```

This one works, but of course no world file.

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, path, df,   resolution = 820 , world_file = True)
```

This produces a result,but it is not in 820 dpi but 96 dpi.

How can I get both the dpi and the world file together?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't have a world file when exporting from the layout view, only from a dataframe.

You need to specify the dataframe in the export parameters, which is why you get the world file in your third line of code.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttotiff.htm

Maybe try setting the height and width to get a higher resolution, and also specifying the geotiff tags = true option.

```
arcpy.mapping.ExportToTIFF(mxd, r"C:\Project\Output\ProjectDataFrame.tif", df,
                           df_export_width=1600,
                           df_export_height=1200,
                           geoTIFF_tags=True)
```